# VPN for university

Tags: networking, vpn

Just wondering how to get VPN working on Ubuntu 12.10 for my University because the instructions aren't very good for Linux (as usual). They have a file which I can open with gedit that contains the following:

```
Description=IT Services  
Host=vpn-gateway.mcc.ac.uk  
AuthType=1  
GroupName=linux  
GroupPwd=  
enc_GroupPwd=050F69C04AECDC0322CAD699CFCDB5579913C3761EF95F2BE74ADA9E4EA678568ED8463E8686760AF824644EE897E8E595079C8419C289C5  
EnableISPConnect=0  
ISPConnectType=0  
ISPConnect=CIGMR  
ISPPhonebook=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk  
ISPCommand=  
Username=  
SaveUserPassword=0  
UserPassword=  
enc_UserPassword=  
NTDomain=  
EnableBackup=0  
BackupServer=  
EnableMSLogon=1  
MSLogonType=0  
EnableNat=1  
TunnelingMode=0  
TcpTunnelingPort=10000  
CertStore=0  
CertName=  
CertPath=  
CertSubjectName=  
CertSerialHash=00000000000000000000000000000000  
SendCertChain=0  
PeerTimeout=90  
EnableLocalLAN=0
```

So I guessed this much:
[image: Screenshot of what I put in]

(The gateway I found on the website somewhere, but it might be wrong)

Any ideas about why it doesn't seem to work? It attempts to connect but just gives up in the end.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the connection? Is it a Cisco VPN?

Comment: I don't know if you can use this link, but these are the instructions on the website: http://www.itservices.manchester.ac.uk/vpn/install/linux/config/
I think it is Cisco

Comment: try using the host provided in the file (vpn-gateway.mcc.ac.uk) instead of the ip

Comment: As the gateway? Ok but I think I've already tried that...  
Yeah that's not working.

Comment: Is it because I can't use the Ubuntu VPN thing under wireless connections, I have to install the Cisco Linux client thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Cisco VPN you have to install the vpnc package
`sudo apt-get install vpnc`

After that you can use VPNC as VPN-connection in the network manager. (new VPN connection and select vpnc)

There you can use the gateway, your user and your password. You also will need the group name and group password. The group name seems to be `linux`(you can see it in your text file). And you will need to encrypt the group-password out of your text file (enc_GroupPwd). You can try to encrypt it here http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/bin/cisco-decode.

If this doesn't work, you should try it with the Cisco Linux VPN client from your University website.

Comment: Thanks, I installed that and ran `pcf2vpnc` in the terminal and that printed the info I needed, then I ran `vpnc-connect` and entered the info. It all connected fine without the link (It must have done that password thing for me) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Ubuntu's native tools and compatible with Cisco's IPSEC client is the [Shrew Soft VPN Client](https://www.shrew.net/software) (free).  Simply install and load up the file provided by the Manchester Computer Centre and you are good to go.